# How to Output MySql rows in Drop Down Menu

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having a Problem in this code :
`

```
                 <?php echo "Choose a date"; 
                     $reservation_date = $rm->retrieveReservation(); 
                              $data_date = array();
                              while($row_date = mysql_fetch_assoc($reservation_date)){
                                array_push($data_date, $row_date);
                                $dateOptions = ""
    .                               "<select class='filter'>"
    .                                  "<option value='<?php echo $row['date']  ; ?>'><?php echo $row['date']  ; ?></option>"
    .                               "</select>";
                                echo $dateOptions;
                              } ?>

                           ?>
```

I want to output Sql row values in a dropdown menu. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apart from the PHP syntax error, what else happens?

Comment: It's just keep on saying Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in

Comment: one of problem is in here: `                                $dateOptions = ""
    .                               "<select class='filter'>"
    .                                  "<option value='{$row['date']}'>{$row['date']}</option>"
    .                               "</select>";`

Comment: I think there are multiple problems there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to echo the `<select>` in the while, you should do like that :

```
 <?php echo "Choose a date"; 
                 $reservation_date = $rm->retrieveReservation(); 
                          $data_date = array();
                          $dateOptions = "<select class='filter'>";
                          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($reservation_date)){
                            array_push($data_date, $row_date);
                            $dateOptions = "<option value='". $row['date']."'>". $row['date'] ."</option>";
                          } ?>
                          $dateOptions = "</select>";
                          echo $dateOptions;
                       ?>
```

Comment: @tomjerry - Hi newuser you should accept the correct answer. You should click on ckeck mark onleft side of each question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
echo "<select class='filter'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($reservation_date)){
    echo "<option value='".$row['date']."'>".$row['date']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

You need to have your `select` tag outside of the loop. You also had a bunch of syntax errors in your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php echo "Choose a date"; 
       echo "<select class='filter'>";
       $reservation_date = $rm->retrieveReservation(); 
              $data_date = array();
              while($row_date = mysql_fetch_assoc($reservation_date)){
                  array_push($data_date, $row_date);
                  $dateOptions = "<option value='{$row['date']}'>{$row['date']}</option>";
                  echo $dateOptions;
              } 
       echo  "</select>";
 ?>
```

may this code will work for you.